# Remove extra row at end of tabular when use \centering

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to make a outlined table with some centered text (and images, but not shown in the example).
This is an example code:

```latex
    \begin{tabular}{|p{16cm}|}
      \hline 
      {\centering{my text}\par}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
```

This works, but adds an empty row at the end of the table. I would like to avoid having this row.

Does anyone knows hot to do this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Remove `\par`, probably.

Comment: @Bernard if he just removes the `\par`, the `\centering` won't have an effect.

Comment: He just has to add it to the table preamble.

Comment: @Bernard see my answer.

Comment: Oh! yes. I'm sorry, I hadn't seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the `array` package and use its facilities to centre a fixed-width column:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{16cm}|}
\hline
my text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\centering` redefines `\\`. Use `\tabularnewline` instead:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{10cm}|}
\hline 
{\centering{my text}\par}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|p{10cm}|}
\hline 
\centering my text\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if `p` is used just for single line fixed width cells, use the `w` column type.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|w{c}{10cm}|}
\hline
my text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a lot of useful info!